# Image across page 100%

Tags: css, image, width, scale

How do I get an image as banner across the page? Below shown is my code, please suggest me a solution.

```
.image {
background: url(banner.jpg) center no-repeat;
width:100%; 
height: 300px; <-- Image height
}
```

the best method?

then apply that css to a classed div?

```
<div class="image" alt="" title="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**put the image inside**

html

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="banner.jpg"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.image {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;/*keeps the image in the container*/
    height: 300px
}
.image img{position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%}/*this is aligned to the bottom, may need to be top or center depending on the circumstances*/
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/srdcY/

Comment: thanks, would you need to use z-index if you wanted to put elements above it? like a css styled button or paragraphed text?

Comment: if the siblings are positioned absolutely and placed after the image, it should naturally be above the image., I've updated the fiddle for that scenario so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation, there are many ways to approach the same problem. The way you described is correct way of doing it as we insert image in to code.

```
<img src="image/source/etc/etc/" alt="" title="" />
```

Comment: but that adds a scroll bar to the page if done that way? or can you apply a 100% width in the <img> tag like <img src="/bla/bal.jpg" width="100%"> or wouldn't that not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a background image then try using CSS background-size property, like so:

```
    .image {
        background-image: url(banner.jpg);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: none;
        background-size: cover; /* or use 'contain' */
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
```

As htmltroll says, there are many ways to approach this.

Comment: thanks @roofdog, would you need to use z-index if you wanted to put elements above it? like a css styled button or paragraphed text?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a need to use `z-index`.